# Angular-Translate Partial loader isn't working

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using AngularJS translate, and If I use it as says the tutorial from pascalprecht my angular app fail and it doesn't show anything (it doesn't load partial views), so I decided to use angular-translate-partial-loader

I have one app menu, and I have a MenuCtrl to display options, I want to translate this menu

Here Is my code

```
 angular.module('myapp'['ngAnimate','ngAria','ngCookies','ngMessages','ngResource','ngRoute','ngSanitize', 'ngTouch', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
.value('language', 'bra')
.run(function ($rootScope, $translate) 
{
  $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () 
        {
          $translate.refresh();
        }
    );
})
.config(function($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
  urlTemplate: 'translations/{lang}/{part}.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage("bra");
})
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});

angular.module('myapp')
.controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope, $translatePartialLoader) {

       $translatePartialLoader.addPart('menu');

        $scope.lItems = [
                    {
                        title: "HOME",
                        class:'active',
                        href:'/',
                        visible: true
                    },
                    {
                        title: "CLASSROOMS",
                        class:'',
                        href:'#',
                        visible: true
                    },    
                    {
                        title: "EXPENSES",
                        class:'',
                        href:'#',
                        visible: true
                    },
                    {
                        title: "EARNINGS",
                        class:'',
                        href:'#',
                        visible: true
                    },
                    {
                        title: "STUDENTS",
                        class:'',
                        href:'#',
                        visible: true
                    }
                ];


 });
```

In index.html

```
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-repeat="lItem in lItems">
                    <li class="{{lItem.class}}"><a href="{{lItem.href}}">{{lItem.title |   translate}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

The trouble was that the menu is out of ng-view block, and when the app loads doesn't refresh the correct html part.

By adding this $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('menu');

```
 .config(function ($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {

    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('menu');   

    $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
     urlTemplate: 'translations/{lang}/{part}.json'
   });
   $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('bra');
```

....

When the application loads the menu part is also loaded.

Comment: $translatePartialLoaderProvider is used to load parts or components when the user demands, Lets says if the user never clicks on "contact" section you shouldn't load the translations for contact page. So let say you have a previous login page and after login succesfully you should now render your menu, now in that part you need to use $translatePartialLoaderProvider. Do you know where should I put $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('menu');? because the config runs when your application loads and that kill the concept of load translate using addPart('menu')

Comment: This should work

angular.module('yourAppName').controller('YourCtrl', ['$scope', '$translate', '$translatePartialLoaderProvider, function($scope, $translate, $translatePartialLoaderProvider)
{

$translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('menu');   

}

Comment: $translatePartialLoaderProvider is not available inside of a controller. :( I don't know how can I request for my backend a new translate table, because I can not do this in controller...

Comment: Hi, you have to write this:     

angular.module('yourApp').run(function ($rootScope, $translate) {
        $rootScope.$on('$translatePartialLoaderStructureChanged', function () {
            $translate.refresh();
        });

and in you controller:

$translatePartialLoader.addPart('team');

Here you have a tutorial about this point. Hope this help you!!

https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/adding-translation-using-angular-translate-to-an-angularjs-app/